# Samsung G530 won't trickle charge when full?

Tags: samsung, charging

Until the past few weeks, I could leave my device plugged in and it'd go to 100% in the morning but recently it seems that once it reaches 100%, it just stops. Not even tricke charge. I've watched it, when it reaches 100%, it acts like it is unplugged and keeps running.  I've had to turn off my device to ensure it does reach 100% for the morning.

I am using original Samsung charger and I've tried different charger (my car is Energizer brand, the battery pack is PNY brand) and I've tried different cable. No matter what I did, once it hits 100% it stops trickling and starts discharging like I unplugged the cable.

Is there a setting in Android that I may have accidentally changed? Or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

Modern batteries disconnect your phone from the charger once it reaches 100%, which is mostly an disadvantage to many people, but the truth is, it helps from battery accidents and problems. Trickle charge is one of the reasons why batteries set on fire, usually because of heat. (But the truth is I don't know more about trickle-charging your phone, letting it reach 101%... Haha!)

An workaround to the draining battery after the disconnection is to try to turn off your phone once it is charging. Don't worry, if you're waiting for an alarm, it will turn your phone automatically.

Answer (score 0):

May have been a recent update or something? I can understand shutting off charging at 100%. The only issue I may get is an emergency phone call at 4 am since incoming call does not power the phone on, and if it doesn't trickle to keep it at 100% while on, then I'm going to have to put up with half-dead phone by morning.